# Redirection fails in IE but is fine with Firefox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I use an `<Authorize>` attribute in ASP.NET MVC to secure a controller.  My page loads portions of its content via AJAX.  Here's a problem I have with IE8, but not Firefox 3.6:

1. Sign in as user JohnDoe and navigate to http://www.example.com/AjaxPage.  Everything works fine.  *AjaxPage* is protected with the `<Authorize>` attribute.
2. Sign out, which redirects me to http://www.example.com.  That page doesn't use `<Authorize>`.
3. Navigate to http://www.example.com/AjaxPage without signing in again.  I should be redirected to the Sign In page since that controller has the `<Authorize>` attribute.

Step 3 works with Firefox, but IE8 displays the non-Ajax portion of http://www.example.com/AjaxPage and then never loads the Ajax content.  I'm surprised any content is displayed at all since I should be redirected to the Sign In page.

My code redirects to the login page with:

```
Return Redirect("https://login.live.com/wlogin.srf?appid=MY-APP-ID&alg=wsignin1.0")
```

Why does Firefox handle this redirection, but IE doesn't?  Since it works the first time (Step 1 above), is there a cache issue?

*EDIT*: I used Fiddler to see if AjaxPage was being cached, but it appears not to be.  I assume if it were cached, I'd get an HTTP Status Code 200 back.  I may simply misunderstand this though.

Comment: What if you define `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]` attribute in your controller? It disables cache.

Comment: LukLed: Yes, that worked! Many thanks. You should post this as an answer so I can give you the points.  Also, see my Edit about Fiddler above.

Comment: LukLed: Fiddler shows nothing for /AjaxPage.  It only shows a 302 redirection for the Ajax content on AjaxPage, but not for AjaxPage itself.  Perhaps this means IE is accessing its local cache.

Comment: Yes, if Fiddler shows nothing, IE used its cache. OutputCache attribute changes this behaviour. You could also change IE settings, but it wouldn't be good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

This attribute, placed in controller class, disables caching. Since I don't need caching in my application, I placed it in my BaseController class:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
```

Here is nice description about OutputCacheAttribute: [Improving Performance with Output Caching](http://www.asp.net/%28S%28pdfrohu0ajmwt445fanvj2r3%29%29/learn/mvc/tutorial-15-cs.aspx)